# How to solve these validations?

Tags: validation

Requirement:  I have 3 fields as Test1,Test2 & Test3.  Test 2 & Test3 are Lookup Fields. If i select Test2 then Test 3 field  need to be required.Test1 is a check box.Here is a validation reule on Test1 as if
Test1 (Not checked) ----> Either Test2 or Test3 should select.
Test2(checked)-----------> Not need to select any thing.

Here My requirement is --------->Test1(not checked)----If test2 selected from lookup then test 3 should be required.

Please guide me how to achieve this by trigger or Validation rule?

Comment: This question is a little confusing, not least because everything is called Test. Can you try to rephrase it so that it's easier to understand?

Comment: I tried to edit/align the question, but there also seems like a problem in your Validation rule. (or not) - You write: Test2 checked - Test2 is a lookup field. did you mean Test1? (feel free to rename to: Test1 --> CB1, Test2,Test3 -->> LF2 and LF3)

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried making a validation rule ? It's very straight forward and self explanatory. You have 2 separate requests, and they can each be done as a validation rule. If I understood correctly:

**If test1(checkbox) is not checked either Test2 (lookup) or Test 3(lookup) should have a selected value.**

```
NOT(Test1) && (ISBLANK(Test2) || ISBLAnk(Test 3))
```

> Please make a selection in Either Test 2 or Test 2 when you do not
>   check Test 1.

**If test2 has a selected value, a lookup selected value is also required in the Test3 lookup.**

```
NOT(ISBLANK(Test2)) && ISBLANK(Test3)
```

> Please select a record in Test3, this is required if you have selected
>   an X in Test 2.